# Symfony2 displaying dynamically values from array to twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I have a function in which I count the final price of each product and I save it in an array. Now when I want do display the values I am stuck at how to display all of them dynamicaly.

This is the function:

```
public function getTotal($items)
{
    $total = array();
    foreach($items as $key=>$item){
        $total[$key] = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscount() + $item->getValue();
    }
    return $total;
}
```

All of the methods getValue, getDiscount and etc are working.

This is how I try o display:

```
{{ getTotal(product)[key]}}
```

The problem is that when I write for example `{{ getTotal(product)[0]}}` or `{{ getTotal(product)[1]}}` and etc i get the correct value, but only of 1 product. I need to get the values from all of them.

If i do `{{ getTotal(product)[key]}}` im getting a strange error:

Key "12" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig at line 89

I have no idea why the key is equal to 12? Maybe I have to write something different?

**UPDATE**
Thank you for the answers, I didnt even think about looping with twig, but I am finally getting some values. However, I dont know why but the twig loop assigns both values for each product.

This is how it should be:

```
Product1 : 0(key):145(value)
Product2 : 1:415
```

But this is how it is:

```
Product1 : 0:145 1:415
Product2 : 0:145 1:415
```

This is the twig:

```
 {% if product is defined %}

            {% for key, item in cart %}

              {% for item in product %}


                <tr>

                  <td> <img width="60" src="{{ asset('bundles/mpFrontend/assets/products/4.jpg') }}" alt=""/></td>

                  <td>{{ item.model }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text">
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.discount }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.value }}</td>

                  {% if getTotal(product) is iterable %}
                    {% for key, sum in getTotal(product) %}

                     <td>{{ key }}:{{ sum }}</td>

                  {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                </tr>

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The error is saying that you have only keys "1" and "2" for your array.

Comment: Yes for now I have only 2 products, so the first product is key 0 and the second is 1

Comment: So you are setting key as 12 somewhere else in your code.. I can't see that, you need to show us the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use twig [for loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html):

```
{% for total in getTotal(product) %}
  {{ total }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are messing up the same variable names in the for cycles. The variable names (key, item) must be unique. So it's also hard for us to guess, what you want to display. But for now it seems, you should change the cycles to something like: `{% for cartKey, cartItem in cart %}` and `{% for productKey, productItem in product %}`.

Comment: Then you could remove the cycle for `getTotal(product)` and jut use `{{ getTotal(product)[productKey] }}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the twig [for](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) loop.

Example:

```
{% if getTotal(product) is iterable %}
    {% for key, sum in getTotal(product) %}
        {{ key }}:{{ sum }}
    {% else %}
        empty array
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You should not use the same `var names` in both of your loops (`key`)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a loop, and move your function from an external to a method of the `product` class.

Instead of loop:

```
<td>{{ product.total }}</td>
```

New function:

```
class Product {
...
    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->getPrice() - $this->getDiscount() + $this->getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: That messes up all of my functions. Why is my code bad?

Comment: Changed my answer, new solution